# Custom Control with Template that allows child control HTML Response to be manipulated

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET Custom Control that has uses ITemplate to allow the developer to place their own inner ASP/HTML controls in it.  The purpose of the control is to parse the rendered HTML of the template contents and search/replace certain placeholder text that might appear (such as [Location], [Division], [FirstName]) with context specific values.

I'm struggling on how to "capture" the generated HTML and "replace" aspects of it as required prior to going out to the response object.

My thoughts are on the lines of using `RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)` to replace output with my own stream and get the controls to write to that.  I can then do what I need to do with the rendered content before sending out to `output`.

However, I am unsure if this is the right method.

Here is a snippet of what I have:

```
/// <summary>
/// This custom control allows replacement fields to be picked up
/// </summary>
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:ReplaceableText runat=\"server\" Text=\"[Text]\"></{0}:ReplaceableText>")]
public partial class ReplaceableText : WebControl
{
    public ReplaceableText()
    {
        TokenReplacer = new TokenReplacer();
    }

    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)]
    public ITemplate Content { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The component the performs the replacement
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// An alternative TokenReplacer component could be installed by the caller if required.
    /// More typically, you will use the AddResolver(s) methods to apply callbacks to do the
    /// actual replacement.
    /// </remarks>
    public ITokenReplacer TokenReplacer { get; set; }



    public bool HasTokenReplacer { get { return (TokenReplacer != null && !DesignMode); } }


    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RenderContents() enter");

        if (HasTokenReplacer)
        {
            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(memStream))
                {
                    using (var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        base.RenderContents(htw);
                    }
                }
                // !! memStream is still empty (0 bytes) !!

                var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memStream.GetBuffer());
                var text2 = TokenReplacer.Convert(text);
                output.Write(text2);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            base.RenderContents(output);
        }

        output.Write(ConvertedText);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RenderContents() exit");
    }


    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        if (Content != null)
        {
            Controls.Clear();
            Content.InstantiateIn(this);    // !!! I need this to write to my own alternative temporary stream 
        }
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }
```

Unfortunately, I don't seem to get any mark-up deposited into my Memory Stream.

Answer (score 0):

Silly sausage that I am, I hadn't put any controls into my `Contents` ITemplate.
This solution does appear to work well, just make sure you check that `Controls.Count > 0` if you find your `MemoryStream` ends up with 0 bytes.